# How map html/css included files to file root not URL path

Tags: php, html

How do I make the following code map to the file path `/my-file.php` instead of the URL path which is `/projects/here`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

This line attempts to include the file `/projects/inc/style.css` which does not exist when it should include the file `/inc/style.css`.

I have used my `.htaccess` file to redirect `/my-file.php` to `/projects/here` which is then mapped back to `/my-file.php` to create a 'clean' URL.

I don't want to have to use `../` as in my particular set-up (this is a simplified version) it would create more work than should be necessary. I expect this will need PHP somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I chose to do was to set a variable that when set, PHP will set another variable to `../` and I put `<?php echo $var; ?>` just before the link and so `$var` is `../` and will thus solve this issue. This could be changed to use the absolute URL at any time, but this fits with my criteria.

In other words, just before every relative URL (that causes an issue - a minority), I have added `<?php echo $var; ?>` and so if I set the correct variable at the beginning of the page which points out that this page is a subdirectory, then `$var` is set to `../` which means that it will be pointing to the correct file to include.

This is by no means an ideal answer, but for my particular situation, this is what I was required to do.

Much thanks to the following answer (which I upvoted) which helped me come to this conclusion (but did not forfill my critera): [How map html/css included files to file root not URL path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198632/how-map-html-css-included-files-to-file-root-not-url-path/19198873#19198873)

Answer (score 1):

Why take so much pain and implement a redirect or rewrite. You can simply provide the absolute url of your css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/inc/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Comment: The reason I didn't do this was because that link was likely to change between `http://www.example.com/my-file.php` and `http://www.example.com/beta/my-file.php` depending on what stage of testing the site was on (and thus `/inc/style.css` would also be moved to `/beta/inc/style.css` and I still need them to map together). That said, I could universally change that value with a PHP include, but I fear that could put unnecessary stress on the server if it must insert the specified URL base every time. Thanks though for the idea, I will do that as a last resort if I cannot find another way.

Comment: Adding that url base is no stress for your PHP, PHP will eat that for dinner

Comment: What I chose to do was to set a variable that when set, PHP will set another variable to `../` and I put `<?php echo $var; ?>` (or similar depending on the coding at the time) and so `$var` is `../` and will thus solve this issue. This could be changed to use the absolute URL at any time, but this fits with my criteria. Feel free to expand your answer with this information so I can mark it as correct as I wouldn't have thought of it if it wasn't for your help.